# I want to perform regular tasks in different URLs at a time.

Tags: batch-file

I want to perform regular tasks in different URLs at a time. Right now using batch file, I can open multiple URLS in active browser in different tabs, but in every opened tab I would like to select option and automatically type the username and password then click on a button.

Batch File Code:

start http://staging-cm3.nature.com/cgi-bin/cManager.pl?path=Top/srep/2015/150923/srep14376
....

Please find below screen-shots of the URLS. http://staging-cm3.nature.com/cgi-bin/cManager.pl?path=Top/srep/2015/150923/srep14386

In the below mentioned screenshot I want to enter username and password and then click on push live button for all opened URLS.

Could any one help on this how to code it batch file?

Thank you very much.

Comment: No, batch file is the wrong choice. Use iMacros addon/extension or similar.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for the suggestion, could you please explain how to use this imacros? I'm new to it.

Comment: I don't use it. Read the tutorial/help/info/examples on iMacros. There could be other ways of accomplishing it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IE, [this link](http://www.visualbasicscript.com/vbscript-Auto-website-login-m98976.aspx) can help you.